# "this is the error happened with me several times in this if statement how to make this code execute properly

Tags: c#, operators, logical-operators

```
using System;

public class HelloWorld
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("please enter xhundred :");
        double xhundred = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine("please enter xT :");
        double xT = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine("please enter xzero :");
        double xzero = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine("please enter t :");
        double T = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
        //this is the if statement of this peace of code
        if ((xhundred , xT , xzero ,T ) < 0 && (  xhundred, xT , xzero ,T ) > 100 ){
            Console.WriteLine("please enter a number from 0 to 100");
        }
        else {
            Console.WriteLine( "l" );
        }
        double t = ((xhundred - xT )/(xhundred - xzero ))*100;
        Console.WriteLine(t);
    }
}
```

at first i went to microsoft learn website and searching on the erroe code (cs0019) and i fond the code will not be running cause of the C# is not convertible to int and cs0019 is also generated when the subtraction operator - is applied to a string. The addition operator + can be used with string
but in my code there is no boolean i think the problem is the   Operator '<' cannot be applied to operands of type '(double, double, double, double)' and 'int'

Comment: You can't compare a tuple to an int. What would it mean this tuple is smaller then 0? The answer to that can't be implicitly in generic code its just in your head. So if you know what that comparison actually should mean put that logic from your head into code name that code a method and call it here instead of the illegal comparison.

Answer (score 1):

You can't compare a tuple and with a single int. You have to do single comparisons for every parameter:

```
if(xhundred < 0 || xT < 0 || xzero < 0 || T < 0 || xhundred > 100 || xT > 100 || xzero > 100 || T > 100)
{
  Console.WriteLine("please enter a number from 0 to 100");
}
```

If you want to compare all variables at once, you can also use LINQ, which is a bit more comfortable:

```
int[] variables = new int[] { xhundred , xT , xzero ,T };
if(variables.Any(x => x < 0 || x > 100))
{
  Console.WriteLine("please enter a number from 0 to 100");
}
```

Or you do every check in a single if, so that the user knows which variable is out of value:

```
Console.WriteLine("please enter xhundred :");
double xhundred = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
if(xhundred < 0 || xhundred > 100)
{
  Console.WriteLine("please enter a number from 0 to 100");
  return;
}
Console.WriteLine("please enter xT :");
double xT = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());

if(xT< 0 || xT > 100)
{
  Console.WriteLine("please enter a number from 0 to 100");
  return;
}
// and so on
```

You can also capsulate that code in a method:

```
private double? ReadValue(string name, int lowerBorder, int upperBorder)
{
    Console.WriteLine("please enter "+name+" :");
    double value = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
    if(value < lowerBorder || value> upperBorder)
    {
      Console.WriteLine("please enter a number from "+lowerBorder+" to "+upperBorder);
      return null;
    }
    return value;
}
```